# Get file original data from Image

Tags: javascript

Im coding a virtual file system for my Javascript application, so I can pack several files in one big binary file, this way I can easily send a project, download it, etc.

My only problem is that I want to pack some images (besides other kind of binary files) and those images I have them stored in variables as Images. I could request the original file using a XMLHttpRequest but I was wondering if it is possible to get the original file from a Image instance, I need the File or Blob from the Image.

It has to be the original file, other solutions wont work (using canvas, etc).

Thanks.